# connecting webcam to opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, webcam-capture

I'm very new to opencv-c++ and I want to connect my webcam and take pictures and do some processing on them. I have searched a lot but I haven't find anything helpful. 
My camera model is: SLEH-00448
I'm working on Qt, Ubuntu 15.04.
Thanks

Comment: why were the houndreds of tutorials google throws in your face for "opencv webcam" not helpful?

Comment: [This](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) link explains how to open camera in opencv. Arguments of `VideoCapture` can be changed to change camera.

Comment: @Sma thanks , but how can I find my device id?

Comment: @Piglet because all of them just work for my laptop's own webcam but I want to use an external one.

Comment: which numbers have you tried and what is the error you get?  0 should be your integrated webcam, 1 your usb webcam...